# Trouble importing file with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to import [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to one of my controllers but I'm getting some errors. It is saved in my Vendors folder and plugins folder.

I've tried adding following to my ItemsController and none have worked

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/vendors/phpQuery.php'); 

App::uses('phpQuery', 'Vendor');

App::import('phpQuery', 'Vendor');
```

All of which result in either an error of not finding the method or

```
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the phpQuery plugin
```

I even tried placing it in the plugins folder and I'm having now luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing Vendor files (especially if they do not stick to regular conventions, like *one class per file*), sometimes requires some variants of the 'normal' `App::import()`

This section in the documentation describes those variants: [Loading Vendor Files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)

I tested this one, and this worked without problems;

```
App::import('Vendor', 'phpQuery');
```

(loads 'app/Vendor/phpQuery.php')

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I have some other errors, but at least it's loading now.